# NodeJS can't save/insert content via MongoJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Iam trying to save/insert in MongoDB

using express and mongoJS

My Code
:

```
var port = 8580;
var express = require ('express');
var app = express ();


// import mongojs Modul
var mongojs = require("mongojs");


//connect
var db = mongojs.connect("localhost:27017/hexx",["users", "reports"]);


//unser Pfad
app.get('/', function(req,res){

    db.users.insert({email: "srirangan@gmail.com", password: "iLoveddMonfxxgodd", sex: "male"});



    console.log("HTTP server running at Port// :" + port);

    db.users.save({created:'just now'});

    console.log(db.users);

});


app.listen(port);
```

When I go to Mongo-Console to "show databases" it will show the new created Database

and when I use in console "db.hexx.users.find()" its empty
and when I insert per 
console "db.hexx.users.insert({email: "srirangan@gmail.com", password: "iLoveddMonfxxgodd", sex: "male"})" - it inserts

In nodeJs its not working

```
db.users.insert({email: "srirangan@gmail.com", password: "iLoveddMonfxxgodd", sex: "male"});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation seems a bit off and misleading but this is what works for me:

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs");

var db = mongojs.connect("localhost/hexx");

var users = db.collection('users');
users.insert({ email: "me@me.com", pasword: "password" });
```

The data will then be present in the collection.

So it seems like the accessor for collections is not implied straight from the `db` variable and you actually need to fetch the collection directly.

Comment: its not working, I have copy&pasted it to server.js and runed  via console

Comment: @user1175380 Would not have posted with "works for me" if I had not tested myself. You are doing something different. I created a new project directory, added the dependency to `packages.json` and the listing above is the content of the sole script being run. Please do that first. Then sort out other conflicts in your application.

Answer (score 0):

i think you console command that wrong ,

try to

```
use hexx;   // from localhost:27017/hexx
db.users.find(); // db.users.insert
```

make sure to select collections correct with

```
show collections;
```